# Python pandas parsing with dataframes

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy, parsing

I'm new to python and I have the following log that I'm trying to parse:

The test.csv file I want to parse looks like:

```
_time, _raw
23.07.2021  10:10:16, examplerandomtext randomtext randomtext <ASD>12123</ASD><ADE>1123</ADE><TYPE>123</TYPE><DATA>1#####33332222####1111122222####</DATA> randomtext randomtext
```

(_raw column)

```
examplerandomtext randomtext randomtext <ASD>12123</ASD><ADE>1123</ADE><TYPE>123</TYPE><DATA>1#####33332222####1111122222####</DATA> randomtext randomtext
```

I have the following code in pycharm:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col="_time")

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['_raw'])

df['DATA'] = df['_raw'].str.extract('<DATA>(.*)</DATA>', expand=True)

df['TYPE'] = df['_raw'].str.extract('<TYPE>(.*)</TYPE>', expand=True)

if not df['_raw'].str.contains('<TYPE>'):
    df['TYPE'] = "321"


print(df.head(10))
```

I want to parse the log so I have three columns and then more... for now it is _time, DATA, TYPE. In some logs there is no `<TYPE>` part and if so I wanna fill the TYPE column with value "321" which I'm trying to do with the if clause (it does not work).

The second step is to store part between `<DATA></DATA>` into a variable based on the content.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if you're creating dummy tags for the example, make sure they open and close correctly: `<asde>12123</asd><adea>1123</awde>` - `asde` closes with `asd`, `adea` closes with `awde`. See how to provide a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And read this post on [how to provide a good pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391). Show what your dataframe looks like with partly filled values for Type and Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['DATA'] = df['_raw'].str.extract('<DATA>(.*)</DATA>')
df['TYPE'] = df['_raw'].str.extract('<TYPE>(.*)</TYPE>').fillna('321')
```

My sample:

```
data = {'_time': {0: '23.07.2021  10:10:16', 1: '23.07.2021  10:10:16'},
 '_raw': {0: 'examplerandomtext randomtext randomtext <ASD>12123</ASD><ADE>1123</ADE><TYPE>123</TYPE><DATA>1#####33332222####1111122222####</DATA> randomtext randomtext',
  1: 'examplerandomtext randomtext randomtext <ASD>12123</ASD><ADE>1123</ADE><DATA>1#####33332222####1111122222####</DATA> randomtext randomtext'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df[['TYPE', 'DATA']]
  TYPE                              DATA
0  123  1#####33332222####1111122222####
1  321  1#####33332222####1111122222####
```

Comment: It seems to be working. Thanks )